# Show the list as clickable

Tags: android, listview

I have obtained a list of URL  and subsequent title from a web service and I would like to show that the list is clickable.

I want to display the title to the users as

```
title 1   >
title 2   >
title 3   >
```

I believe the > signs denotes that these titles are clickable and would do something at launch

I have tried setting

```
android:clickable="true"
```

and also

```
android:clickable="true"
```

but one of these options show  > in my list.

I have already implemented the setOnClickListener() and am able to launch URL with that however what I would like to do is display > next to the list to show they are clickable links.

Using the response given I have now managed to show the image.
However as the title is 3-4 lines long but I see the image only on the first line. Is there any android: (settings) which I can set which would allow the image to be aligned right and centre of the list row?

Comment: you don't need a ">" mark to make it clickable, try using `setOnItemClickListener` on your list view. If you want that sign though, create a custom layout for your list view

Comment: What controls are you using to display this list?

Comment: Are you displaying these titles in a ListView or anything? Simply adding ">" to them does not make them clickable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not in the default Android behavior.

You can find an image with the same shape, save it as something like link_arrow_right.png in your drawable folder, and use it on the TextViews that display clickable links.

This can be done in two ways:

1) In your layout xml, in your link text view item:
`android:drawableRight="@drawable/link_arrow_right"`

2) In your code, programatically:

`yourTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.link_arrow_right, 0)`